# PHP retrieve distinct data from database based on two rows

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have table named `messages` with some rows:

```
+---------+
| columns |
+---------+
| id      |
| from    |
| to      |
| body    |
| date    |
+---------+
```

What I want is to retrieve a list of users I message or users who messaged me.

```
public function get_users_m($where)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('messages');
    $this->db->where($where); // to = my_id or from = my_id 
    $this->db->group_by('from, to');

    return $this->db->get()->result_array();
}
```

I made that using Codeigniter but the problem is when I reply, for example to `C`, I get A (me) send message to `C` and `C` send message to `A` and I don't want that I want just `C` one time because it doesn't matter if i'm the one who sent him message or he is the one who send me the message it still the same user.

Comment: Can you break up your last sentence into two or more sentences? It's long and hard to read.

Comment: @user151841 i guess the important thing is to understand the idea. this is what i need . i have a table named messages and i want a list of all users i exchange messages with. i hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this

```
public function get_users_m()
{
    $my_id = 5; # some id
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('messages');
    $this->db->where('from == $my_id');
    $this->db->or_where('to == $my_id'); # add this or_where Clause
    $this->db->group_by('user_id');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result;
}
```

Check comment of [Tpojka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34291670/php-retrieve-distinct-data-from-database-based-on-two-rows/34292282?noredirect=1#comment56327324_34292282)

Comment: Comparision should be with one equal sign (i.e. `$this->db->where('from = $my_id');`) or in CI way `$this->db->where('from', $my_id);`.

Comment: @Tpojka yes i know i remove one equal sign, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You are using user_id and profile_id both. You have mentioned which field belongs to other user. Is it user_id or profile_id.

Let's consider that other user id is profile_id.

Following query will help you get distinct profile_id who replied to you or you replied to them but not yours.

```
public function get_users_m($where)
    {
        $this->db->select('profile_id');
        $this->db->from('messages');
        $this->db->where('profile_id != your profile id'); 
        $this->db->group_by('profile_id');
        return $this->db->get()->result_array();
    }
```